# Nonsplit extension of $\mathbb{Z}$ by itself

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, exact-sequence, group-extensions

I was classifying all split extensions on a list of short exact sequences, when I arrived on this one:
$$1 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 1$$
That the automorphism group $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to $C_2$ is not hard to work out, and my job to classify split extensions ends pretty much there, once there are only two homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $C_2$.

But when I thought about nonsplit extensions on this sequence, I started wondering, is there one? Over finite groups, some light on this matter can be shed using theorems like Lagrange, Cauchy and Sylow, but my knowledge on infinite groups give me no arguments, neither to claim existence or to deny it.

So, do exist a nonsplit extension of $\mathbb{Z}$ by itself?

Comment: Are you familiar with projective modules? $\mathbb Z$ is a free $\mathbb Z$-module. Thus, every short exact sequence ending in $\mathbb Z$ splits.

Comment: @AymanHourieh In category of abelian groups sure but if we are talking about groups there are extentions ending in $\mathbb Z^2$ which do not split, like the discrete Heisenberg group (the central extention). You do have the right idea though, which Erik's answer mentions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every extension $1\to A\to B\stackrel{p}\to\mathbb{Z}\to 1$ splits, since you can get a splitting $i:\mathbb{Z}\to B$ by choosing any $x\in B$ such that $p(x)=1$ and defining $i(n)=x^n$.  More generally, a similar argument applies with $\mathbb{Z}$ replaced by any free group.

Answer (score 0):

There does not exist a non split extension of $Z$ by itself since $H^2(Z,Z)=0$.

Comment: Searching up how I would calculate $H^2(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$ was the first thing I thought of, once it could give me info on the nonsplit extensions. But because my knowledge of group cohomology is still very immature, I was trying to avoid arguments of the sort. This question is more out of curiosity anyway, and it's good to know various ways to show it.

Comment: Calculating this cohomology group only tells you about central extensions.

Comment: It is a very basic fact of group theory that is attached to an extension an element of $H^2$ which vanishes if and only if the extension splits.

Comment: No, that's only true for central extensions.

Comment: You may look in an book on the subject. If you have an extension $1\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow 1$ where $A$ is commutative, let $p:B\rightarrow C$ and $p(c')=c$. Let $a\in A, c'a{c'}^{-1}$ does not depend of $c'$ above $c$ since $A$ is commutative, verify,.. then you have a representation $C\rightarrow Aut(A)$ and $A$ is a $C$-module, let $h:C\rightarrow B$ such that $p(h(c))=c$ verify that $h(cd){h(d)}^{-1}{h(c)}^{-1}$ is a $2$-cocycle in $C^2(C,A)$ whose class does not depend of the choice made, verify again obviously it is the obstruction of the splitting.